# Deleting registry entries using a registry file and reg.exe

Tags: windows-registry

I have a registry file which I use with reg.exe to install COM files on users computer.

The batch file does this upon installation

```
reg import C:\Stuff\MySoftware.reg /reg:32
```

Can I just use reg delete to uninstall, or remove the same entries from the registry? Like this..

```
reg delete C:\Stuff\MySoftware.reg
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do it like this.

To delete a registry key with a .reg file, put a hyphen (-) in front of the RegistryPath in the .reg file. Like:

```
[-RegPath]
```

Now do:

```
Reg import "filepath" /Reg:32
```